# IE9 won't execute the default action for a link, if it's disabled during the click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer-9

To prevent users from submitting a form twice, I disable the submit button after a click with:

```
$('a').on('click', function(){
    $(this).button('option', 'disabled', true);
});
```

​

On Chrome, the default action (following the link / executing the JS in the `href` attribute) is executed. On IE9 however, nothing happens and the button stays disabled. I tried poking around it in the respective JS debuggers and it seems both events are processed in the same phase.

You can see it in action on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/inerdial/yXWBn/2/

Is there any reason for this behaviour, and/or a workaround less hackish than manually triggering the button's default action somehow?

In case it's any relevant, the submit button is an ASP.NET LinkButton, styled with jQuery UI.

Comment: You can try putting that logic into a `setTimeout` call.

Comment: @Matthew D'oh, I forgot about that. It works, can you make this an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try putting that logic into a `setTimeout` call

Answer (score 3):

You have to set `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` on the submit button and everything will work as expected.

Comment: These are all `LinkButton`s, those don't have that property, as they presumably can't work using a form submit anyway.